# Using Openssl API to read all X509 certificates from a folder in C

Tags: c, openssl, x509

In an application (in C language), I would need to attach all the CA certificates available locally. So, I'm looking for some Openssl library function that could help me to load all the certificates in X509 format from a given folder (or certificate store), for example /etc/ssl/certs directory. I would appreciate any help in this regards.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is what you wanted: [SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html)?

I understand the OpenSSL documentation is dense, but you're going to have to be able to find what you need in it (and not via a stackoverflow question).

Make sure if you added new certificates to that directory that you re-run c_rehash, as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Hi Macattack, Thanks for your reply but this isn't what I wanted. I'm aware of this function and I know we can use it to load certificates from CAPath dir for building the certificate chain against which the authenticity of a certificate can be verified. But what I really want to know is how to pull those certificates in a variable to be used for some other purpose (say, for creating a payload).

Comment: Ah, my apologies then, I jumped to conclusions. Off the top of my head I don't know of any way to do what you're suggesting, it may exist somewhere. Good luck.